# GraphQL Nestjs Apollo Autocompletar campos

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo

Estoy construyendo un GrapqhQL con nestjs y las librerias de apollo y graphql.

Quiero saber si hay alguna forma de que en el playground los campos se puedan llamar todos, es decir,

```
query { 
       consulta {
       ... campos ...
       }
}
```

Como se ve más arriba, la forma en la que uno llama a los campos es uno por uno, ctrl + espacio te deja ver los campos de la consulta, pero debes agregarlos 1 a 1, ¿hay un atajo para que se pongan todos, o algo que se deba añadir al código para tener esta funcionalidad? Busqué, pero no di con alguna solución.